# Bound for integral-sum estimate using the total variation

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with total variation $V$. Let $\{\vartheta_k\}$ denote the equidistant points $\vartheta_k = \frac{2\pi}{2(n+1)}(2k-1)$ where $n$ is some positive integer. I want to show that
$$\left|\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}f(\vartheta_k)-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(\theta)d\theta\right|\leq \frac{V}{2(n+1)}$$
but I can only get $\leq \frac{V}{n+1}$. The book that I'm reading is suggesting that the above inequality should be true so I am wondering if this is so.

**My estimate:** Let $h = \frac{2\pi}{2(n+1)}$. Then since $2h(n+1) = 2\pi$
$$\left|\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}f(\vartheta_k)-\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(\theta)d\theta\right| = \left|\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{2h}\int_{\vartheta_k-h}^{\vartheta_k+h}f(\vartheta_k)d\theta-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(\theta)d\theta\right| \\ = \left|\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\int_{\vartheta_k-h}^{\vartheta_k+h}f(\vartheta_k)-f(\theta)d\theta\right| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\int_{\vartheta_k-h}^{\vartheta_k+h}|f(\vartheta_k)-f(\theta)|d\theta \\ \leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}2h|f(\vartheta_k)-f(\tilde\vartheta_k)| = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}|f(\vartheta_k)-f(\tilde\vartheta_k)|\leq \frac{V}{n+1}$$
where I applied the mean value theorem of integral calculus to get the points $\tilde\vartheta_k$. Now I know that the last inequality is probably strict but I don't see another method which would give the $\frac{1}{2}$ in front.

Comment: Look up Koksma's inequality. See if it gives the factor of $2$. If so, look at its proof.

Comment: This seems to do the trick, why not add as an answer so that I can mark the question as answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up Koksma's inequality. See if it gives the factor of 2. If so, look at its proof.